# Swiper JS Transition issue

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider, swiper.js

i have created slider using swiper js. i have achieved layout using css. but issue when i tried to give transition on image doesnt give proper effect of transition

i have created slider using swiper js .. but the isssue is when i add transition to slider then transition not working properly here the my code
swiper js
swiper css

```
<head>
    <style>
        .swiper-container {
            width: 100% !important;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .swiper-slide-active {
            width: 87.5% !important;
        }

        .swiper-slide-next,
        .swiper-slide-next+.swiper-slide {
            width: 5% !important;
            text-align: center;
            transition: none;
        }

        .swiper-slide img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            object-fit: cover;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .swiper-button-next:after,
        .swiper-button-prev:after {
            content: none;
        }

        .swiper-button-prev {
            left: -7px;
        }

        .swiper-button-next {
            right: -7px;
        }

        .swiper-button-next,
        .swiper-button-prev {
            align-items: center;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 6%);
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
            color: #000;
        }

        /* .swiper-slide {
      transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    } */
        .swiper-slide {
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        }

        @media(max-width: 640px) {

            .swiper-slide-next,
            .swiper-slide-next+.swiper-slide {
                width: 10% !important;
                text-align: center;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Swiper js with animation</h2>
                <div class="swiper-container">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div><img src="images/img2.webp" alt=""></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div><img src="images/img3.webp" alt=""></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div><img src="images/img4.webp" alt=""></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div><img src="images/img5.webp" alt=""></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div><img src="images/img6.webp" alt=""></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Add Pagination -->
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <!-- Add Arrows -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/8.4.5/swiper-bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-wdUM0BxMyMC/Yem1RWDiIiXA6ssXMoxypihVEwxDc+ftznGeRu4s9Fmxl8PthpxOh5CQ0eqjqw1Q8ScgNA1moQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            loop: true,
            slidesPerGroup: 1,
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
                type: 'fraction',
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
            // autoplay: {
            //   delay: 3000,
            //   disableOnInteraction: false,
            // },
            // Add cubic bezier animation
            transition: {
                duration: 6000,
                easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.93, 0.24, 0.74, 0.6)',
                runCallbacks: true
            },

        });
        var prevButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');
        prevButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i>';
        var nextButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');
        nextButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>';
    </script>
</body>
```

i want slider something like this using swiper js ridibooks.com/webtoon/recommendation this is just for reference here's the my code codepen.io/sapnas/pen/xxJXmBm

Comment: This indeed looks like a transition issue. try changing your transition from .6s to 10s and change your delay: 10000 then watch your animations. Also looks like you want everything right aligned and then expand from that side. I am not sure how to archive that with now.

Comment: thanks i have tried but its not working do you have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

The SwiperJS transition we have hopefully solved at this codepen example.
You still need to refine your code further to suit your specific goal.
[codepen example](https://codepen.io/crux1/pen/qByPyMV).
Bootstrap: we attempted to duplicate it as well (set to 'col-md-6 col-lg-4') but the bootstrap version was not known in your post.
Some of the code used will not be needed in your further refinements (i.e. CSS .bk1).
In SwiperJS version #8 some minor script code has changed from .swiper-container to just .swiper and these differences may be causing part of your error.

```
<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    slidesPerView: 3, ....
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i want slider something like this using swiper js https://ridibooks.com/webtoon/recommendation this is just for reference                      
 here's the my code https://codepen.io/sapnas/pen/xxJXmBm